# Hide/Snooze issues in YouTrack

Tags: youtrack

I want to use YouTrack for Key-Account-Management.

There is one Epic and for each key account (customer) one sub-issue.

I want to talk to each key account roughly every 6 months.

Is there a way to hide or snooze an issue for some time.

The issue should be like resolved for some months, and then come back if the snooze time has expired.

How to do this with youtrack?

Comment: Maybe moving the issues to an icebox epic/user story and setting the due date?

Comment: Related: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/62192/inbox-zero-for-android

Comment: Related: I like the n-days-later-method: https://github.com/guettli/n-days-later-method It would solve above question

Comment: I opened an issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-53399 to raise awareness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The issue should be like resolved for some months

It seems that one can simply resolve the issue to accomplish it.
The tricky part is to reopen them automatically in 6 months. The following [workflow rule](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Workflow-Rules.html) can reopen YouTrack issues by timer:

```js
var entities = require('@jetbrains/youtrack-scripting-api/entities');
var workflow = require('@jetbrains/youtrack-scripting-api/workflow');

exports.rule = entities.Issue.onSchedule({
  title: workflow.i18n('Reopen issues in 6 months'),
  search: '#Resolved',    // Narrow the search to specify which issues are affected
  cron: '0 0 0 ? * * *',  // Fires once a day
  guard: function(ctx) {
    // If an issue was in a resolved state for half a year already...
    return Date.now() - ctx.issue.resolved < 15552000000;
  },
  action: function(ctx) {
    // ... then reopen it
    ctx.issue.State = ctx.State.Open;
  },
  requirements: {
    State: {
      type: entities.State.fieldType,
      Open: {}
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I guess it works. But the timedelta is fixed. `+Nx` would be great. With x being d for days , w for weeks, m for months would be great. "d" should be the default and optional.

Comment: Related: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/62192/inbox-zero-for-android

Comment: I fail to see how this is related, since the solution provided here is YouTrack specific.

Comment: I  have a goal called "zero inbox". There are several inboxes: Issues in youtrack, issues on github, mails, notes on paper, ...

Comment: Can't help you with that. The solution above is designed to handle issues in YouTrack bug tracking system only.